# SubSonic 3.0 - Medium Trust

Tags: subsonic

In June 2009 SubSonic 3.0 was released. Because I'm looking for an ORM solution for my website which is able to work in a medium trust environment this looks an option. 
From searching this site I noted that SubSonic 2.0 is able to work in a medium trust environment. With respect to 3.0 I could not find this on the web.

Does anyone has any experience yet with 3.0 in a medium trust environment (at an ISP)? And what are the do and don't issues. I tested this briefly locally but security exceptions were thrown. Before implementing any further this I would like to know because I was already disappointed by Nhibernate an a medium trust environment.

Comment: Please provide a link to this product - the SVN I know of is a SCM.

Comment: Are you getting SubVersion and SubSonic mixed up?

Answer (score 2):

We tested this in medium trust and currently there are no issues.

Comment: This is still an issue with the current release (a year and a half after your answer)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to test this out. The only issue I had with Active Record was pulling from the 'data context' object.  Anytime I pulled from  DBContext.TableNames and used a function like Where() or Count() under medium trust, it would throw a SecurityException.

I was successfully able to pull single rows using the constructors, and I was also able to save and delete them using Active Record with no medium trust issues.

For the listing problem, I bugged it here. Feel free to add to it if you have anything. 
http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/#issue/99

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a new ORM Framework being released this month that supports Medium Trust.  FlyweightObjects.NET is also an out-of-the box architecture.  You might want to check it out when it releases.
[link text](http://flyweightobjects.blogspot.com/2009/09/flyweightobjectsnet-features-and.html)